# Meteor.isServer and Meteor.isClient usage

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to understand how to use **isServer / isClient**
I have a .jsx file located in imports/ui/components/User/Login.jsx

inside I tried to call Meteor.isServer, Meteor.isClient but both values is undefined. I'm very newbie to Meteor and can't understand this behavior.

```
import Meteor from 'meteor/meteor';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export class Login extends React.Component {

onSubmit(){
    //code omitted

    console.log(Meteor.isClient);
    console.log(Meteor.isServer);
}
render() {
    return (
        <div className="row">
            //code omitted
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Comment: Should be what you expect. See [the docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-isClient). Where are you running the code? Try to log the `Meteor` object itself to the console and see all of its properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think `Meteor` is the default export, so I think you need to write `import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor'`.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, in JavaScript the function context is defined when **calling** the function, not while defining it.

Meteor is defined (imported) in your Login component. But onSubmit() is an event handler which might (depending on how/to what you bind it) be called from many contexts.

The Meteor object needs to be available in the context where onSubmit() is called.

What you could try (hard to know without seeing more code) is to explicitly bind the event handler to the component. Add a constructor like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created some meteor apps (nothing really big) before Meteor 1.3, now everything is changed. Next app I will give a try to [Mantra JS](https://mantrajs.com/) an architecture framework over Meteor, his creator (Arunoda Susiripala) is a meteor guru that written a lot of useful packages.

Why am I saying this? Because Mantra JS define how client and server module  should be created and force you to structure your app following a pattern that should lead to maintainability, testability and code separation